# I changed laragon php version to 8 and after that apache won't run

Tags: php, apache, laragon

I changed laragon php version to 8 and after that apache won't run Here is the error:

```
Service apache can not start C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.46vs16/conf.... Syntax error on line 2 Api module structure php8_module error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, update your Apache version.

After go to c:\laragon\etc\apacke2\mode_php.conf

change: `LoadModule php8_module` to `LoadModule php_module`

The overall change:

From this:

```
# This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php8_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

To this:

```
# This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

so `php8_module` will be `php_module`

[reference](https://medium.com/laravelarticle/php-8-apache-can-not-start-fixed-c62b0a0e4f0a)

Comment: https://medium.com/laravelarticle/php-8-apache-can-not-start-fixed-c62b0a0e4f0a